# Signing certificate inside a docker container?

Tags: .net, docker, ssl-certificate, devops, .net-6.0

I have a certificate stored in the Windows certificate store. I've written a .NET 6 application which accesses this certificate (with it's private key) to sign something.

Certificate retrieval code:

```
var thumbprint = "thumbprint_from_config";
var signingCert = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser).DoWith(x => x.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)).Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false).FirstOrDefault();
if (signingCert == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot find certificate with thumbprint {thumbprint}");
}
```

Outside of the container, the application is able to access the certificate with no problems.

However, I'm trying to run this application in a Docker container (on my local machine), but I'm recieving the error from earlier, suggesting it cannot find the certificate:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find certificate with thumbprint [CORRECT_THUMBPRINT_HERE].
```

If I change the certificate store from CurrentUser to LocalMachine (which is what it should be set to IMO), I see this error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unix LocalMachine X509Store is limited to the Root and CertificateAuthority stores
```

Is there an industry-accepted best practice for handling certificates in Docker? There seems to be lots of missing/conflicting information online about the best way to go about this.

For completeness, here's my `dockerfile` in it's entirety:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APP_NAME.dll"]
```

Comment: Information of how you are trying to load the cenrtificate in your container is probably a good idea to include.

Comment: Good point, I will add now :)

Comment: If you're using WSL2, then your docker container is run on a Linux VM behind the scenes. That Linux VM doesn't have access to the certificate store on the Windows host. I don't know if it's possible to map the Windows certificate store into the container. My guess would be that it isn't.

Comment: I think you'll need to get the certificate into the container and load it as a file providing the path within the container to it. something like  `RUN powershell Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\certs\cert1.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My# Confirming the installation of the certificateRUN powershell ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My`

Comment: @a_e, this approach would mean every container would require a new release when the certificate needs renewing. Also, there are potential security impacts with including a full certificate/private key in a container.

Comment: That's true, in that case. You will have use Docker secrets to manage your certificates. And read them from there. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Comment: Ahh, this might be what I'm after... Will read now, thank you!

Comment: The link provided by @a_e is specific to Docker Swarm. If you're not using Swarm, there are other ways to safely inject secrets into the container by using a secret mount: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information

Comment: Yeah, this would likely need to use plain Docker.

According to that document, secrets are only exposed to Linux containers.

I'm using Windows, and will likely be hosting on Windows (though I could maybe look more into WSL).

Comment: You can export your certificate into base64 string and then pass this string trough environment variable into your container (regular setting in [`appsettings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-of-environment-variables-1) would work). That variable can later be initialized with secret or whatever you wish. Just a level of abstraction